# please with Formula in excel worksheet how to link

Tags: excel-formula

What I have is excel workbook .I have two sheets with 1 -  25 rows and 7 columns and tabled . The first sheet column on each sheet is titled (lines) . The first sheet is also numbered down the column 1-24 . The 2nd sheet also has the first column name (lines), but not numbered down the

numbered down the column 1-24 . The 2nd sheet also has the first column name (lines), but not numbered down the column. What I’m looking to do for example is if I entered the number 1 on the 2nd sheet in any position down the (lines) column it would automatically copy the number one row across that row . Or if I entered the number 5 on row 10 of the 2nd sheet it would copy row 5 onto row 10 of sheet 2 . Any help would greatly be appre

Comment: This is a vague description, let me see if I am interpreting this right.  Sheet 1 is the master data table, it contains 24 rows of 7 cells of data.  It's the only sheet that contains data.  If you go to sheet 2, or 10, or whichever, and you enter `7` in cell A4, or A7, or A10, you want that row to be populated with the seven values from row 7 on sheet 1?  How I would do this will depend on whether you have Excel O365 or not.

Comment: You can use `INDEX/MATCH` on any Excel-Version or `FILTER` on Excel 365. There are enough tutorials around for each solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have excel 365, I’ll try to clarify.sheet 1 has 24 rows . Each of them have 7 columns. With data . Sheet 2 is the same amount of rows and columns without data . I’m trying to copy 5 of the columns from sheet 1. One row at a time from sheet 1 to sheet 2. With a 1 key entry on sheet 2, and copying it to any row I choose on sheet 2.

Comment: You might be better off adding a photo of your spreadsheet and re-explaining what you would like done. It's very hard to follow without a visual representation.